# How to convert lavavel collection to square bracket collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have laravel livewire collection as below.

```
  [
    {
    "date":"2021.09.01-0:00",
    "open":110.177,
    "close":110.175,
    "low":110.172,
    "high":110.18
    },
    {
    "date":"2021.09.01-0:01",
    "open":110.175,
    "close":110.171,
    "low":110.169,
    "high":110.175
    },
    {
    "date":"2021.09.01-0:02",
    "open":110.171,
    "close":110.173,
    "low":110.17,
    "high":110.176
    }
  ]
```

I would like to convert them into form of square bracket collection without key name as below .

```
$data = [
          ['2021.09.01-0:00',110.177,110.175,110.172,110.18],
          ['2021.09.01-0:01',110.175,110.171,110.169,110.175],
          ['2021.09.01-0:02',110.171,110.173,110.17,110.176]
       ];
```

Any advice or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: where does this Collection of data come from? ... are these objects or associative arrays that the JSON is representing?

Comment: Dear lagbox, Collection is getting from laravel eloquent. I would like to convert them to new collection for javascript usage purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use collection `map` method:

> The map method iterates through the collection and passes each value to the given callback. The callback is free to modify the item and return it

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-map

```
$expectData = $collection->map(fn($item) => [$item-> date, $item->open,...])
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what the original data is but you can `map` over the collection and pull the values; if Eloquent Models:

```
$data->map(fn ($v) => array_values($v->toArray()))
```

Would depend upon how you got that original Collection for how it would end up in this scenario.

If you need to restrict what attributes and the order of them returned you can use `only` on the model:

```
fn ($v) => array_values($v->only(['date', ...]))
```

Comment: Dear Iagbox, Not work. I try  $stocks = StockData::take(4)->get();
        $stocks->map(fn ($v) => array_values((array) $v));
        return $stocks;. But result is not expected.

Comment: that isn't the answer, it was updated .... also `map` returns a new collection so returning the original wouldn't help as it is unchanged

Comment: Dear lagbox, thank you very much.